# Storing dates in an array in Libreoffice Basic

Tags: arrays, date, macros, libreoffice, basic

For the last few days I have been researching this without finding an answer. I have a list of transactions from which I filter a subset. For the subset I store the date and the amount in an array, to use in a XIRR calculatation.

The input column is tested with 'IsDate' and is found to be True. Furthermore, I use 'ReDim Preserve (0 to n) As Date' when storing the Dates. However, when testing the result, the array does not contain Dates but Doubles.

Please refer to the code below.

```
Function FundXIRRTotal(ByVal FundISIN As String, ByVal KiesDatum As Date) As Double

Dim wshT As Object
Dim wshS As Object
Dim wshP As Object
Dim wsh As Object
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim NumberOfTrans As Long
Dim Guess As Double
Dim arrValues() As Double
Dim arrDates() As Date
Dim oFA As Object

Set wshT = ThisComponent.Sheets.getByName("Transacties")
Set wshP = ThisComponent.Sheets.getByName("Portefeuille")
Set wshS = ThisComponent.Sheets.getByName("Instellingen")

'Find Last Used Row
wsh = wshT.createCursor
wsh.gotoEndOfUsedArea( False )
LastRow = wsh.getRangeAddress().EndRow

NumberOfTrans = 0

'Create Transaction Array
For i = 1 To LastRow
    If wshT.getCellByPosition(3, i).String = FundISIN And CDate(wshT.getCellByPosition(0, i).Value) <= KiesDatum Then

        ReDim Preserve arrValues(0 To NumberOfTrans) As Double
        ReDim Preserve arrDates(0 To NumberOfTrans) As Date

        arrDates(NumberOfTrans) = CDate(wshT.getCellByPosition(0, i).Value)

        If wshT.getCellByPosition(1, i).String = wshS.getCellRangeByName("FundBuy").String Then
            arrValues(NumberOfTrans) = -CDbl(wshT.getCellByPosition(9, i).Value / wshT.getCellByPosition(10, i).Value)
        End If

        If wshT.getCellByPosition(1, i).String = wshS.getCellRangeByName("FundSell").String Then
            arrValues(NumberOfTrans) = CDbl(wshT.getCellByPosition(9, i).Value / wshT.getCellByPosition(10, i).Value)
        End If

        If wshT.getCellByPosition(1, i).String = wshS.getCellRangeByName("FundDeposit").String Then
            arrValues(NumberOfTrans) = CDbl(wshT.getCellByPosition(9, i).Value / wshT.getCellByPosition(10, i).Value)
        End If

        If wshT.getCellByPosition(1, i).String = wshS.getCellRangeByName("FundDivCash").String Then
            arrValues(NumberOfTrans) = CDbl(wshT.getCellByPosition(9, i).Value / wshT.getCellByPosition(10, i).Value)
        End If

        If wshT.getCellByPosition(1, i).String = wshS.getCellRangeByName("FundDivShares").String Then
            arrValues(NumberOfTrans) = CDbl(wshT.getCellByPosition(9, i).Value / wshT.getCellByPosition(10, i).Value)
        End If

        If wshT.getCellByPosition(1, i).String = wshS.getCellRangeByName("FundSplit").String Then
            arrValues(NumberOfTrans) = -CDbl(wshT.getCellByPosition(9, i).Value / wshT.getCellByPosition(10, i).Value)
        End If

        If wshT.getCellByPosition(1, i).String = wshS.getCellRangeByName("FundFee").String Then
            arrValues(NumberOfTrans) = -CDbl(wshT.getCellByPosition(9, i).Value / wshT.getCellByPosition(10, i).Value)
        End If

        If wshT.getCellByPosition(1, i).String = wshS.getCellRangeByName("FundWarUit").String Then
            arrValues(NumberOfTrans) = -CDbl(wshT.getCellByPosition(9, i).Value / wshT.getCellByPosition(10, i).Value)
        End If

        NumberOfTrans = NumberOfTrans + 1      

    End If
Next i

'Add current value to Array
'NumberOfTrans = NumberOfTrans + 1
ReDim Preserve arrValues(0 To NumberOfTrans) As Double
ReDim Preserve arrDates(0 To NumberOfTrans) As Date
arrValues(NumberOfTrans) = CDbl(Waarde(FundISIN, KiesDatum))
arrDates(NumberOfTrans) = CDate(KiesDatum)

If Portfolio(FundISIN, KiesDatum) = 0 Then
    FundXIRRTotal = 0
    Exit Function
End If

'Calculate XIRR
oFA = createUNOService("com.sun.star.sheet.FunctionAccess")
FundXIRRTotal = oFA.callFunction("XIRR", Array(arrValues()), Array(arrDates()))

End Function
```

I am aware of the issue with the Array function where the data type gets lost. I tried to overcome that by creating a new Array As Date, and copying from arrDates to the new one. But no luck, doubles again...

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you put the resulting array of doubles into the spreadsheet, and format the cells as dates, do they display correctly?  (If the doubles are days since December 31, 1899 - the way spreadsheets internally store dates regardless of the display setting - this should work.)

Comment: Yes, they do display correctly when I put the resulting array in a sheet and format them as dates. But I am looking for a way to feed this ad-hoc array of dates to the XIRR function, and that is the part that does not seem to work (as the array contains the number equivalents of the dates, but not stored as dates).

Comment: Will the XIRR function take a string date as an input?

Comment: Good question! As far as I could, the XIRR needs numerical values and dates. But I tried to 'feed' it the dates as strings, and that gave the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number *is* the date.  The UNO `FunctionAccess` call will not accept the OpenOffice Basic `Date` type, and expects a number type instead.

Here is working example code:

```vb
Function FundXIRRTotal(ByVal FundISIN As String, ByVal KiesDatum As Date) As Variant
    Dim wshT As Object
    Dim i As Long
    Dim arrValues(0, 2) As Double
    Dim unoDates(0, 2) As Double
    Dim theDate As Double
    Dim oFA As Object
    Dim args(2) As Variant
    Dim result As Variant

    Set wshT = ThisComponent.Sheets.getByName("Transacties")
    For i = 0 To 2
        arrValues(0, i) = wshT.getCellByPosition(3, i).Value
        'The date value will be a number, for example 42020 for 2015-01-16.
        theDate = wshT.getCellByPosition(2, i).Value
        unoDates(0, i) = theDate
    Next i
    oFA = createUNOService("com.sun.star.sheet.FunctionAccess")
    args = Array(arrValues, unoDates)
    result = oFA.callFunction("XIRR", args)
    FundXIRRTotal = result
End Function
```

See also https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=67996.

By the way, I also tried using [com.sun.star.util.Date](https://www.openoffice.org/api/docs/common/ref/com/sun/star/util/Date.html) but that did not seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, create a sheet called "TempSheet".  It can be hidden, because it will just be used for temporary processing.

In FundXIRRTotal, write `arrDates` to TempSheet column A.  Then pass that cell range to `oFA.callFunction()`.

Below is the working code I used to test this concept.  Change "C1:C3" to the range on TempSheet that contains the contents of `arrDates`, for example `"TempSheet.A1:A" & Ubound(arrDates)`.

```vb
Function FundXIRRTotal(ByVal FundISIN As String, ByVal KiesDatum As Date) As Double
    Dim wshT As Object
    Dim i As Long
    Dim arrValues(2, 0) As Double
    Dim arrDates(2, 0) As Date
    Dim args as Array
    Dim oFA As Object

    Set wshT = ThisComponent.Sheets.getByName("Transacties")
    For i = 0 To 2
        arrDates(i, 0) = wshT.getCellByPosition(2, i).Value
        arrValues(i, 0) =  wshT.getCellByPosition(3, i).Value    
    Next i
    oFA = createUNOService("com.sun.star.sheet.FunctionAccess")
    args = Array(arrValues, wshT.getCellRangeByName("C1:C3"))
    FundXIRRTotal = oFA.callFunction("XIRR", args)
End Function
```

Note: I recommend my other answer instead of this one.